# Add parquet-tools to path (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio, parquet, parquet-mr

I am trying to use this [parquet-viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dvirtz.parquet-viewer) so I can easily view parquet files in Visual Studio Code.

It requires that [parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) are available in the path.

I did

```
brew install parquet-tools
```

and when I try to open my .parquet file with Visual Studio Code I see the binary instead of viewing the contents of the file.

Before installing parquet-tools with homebrew, Visual Studio Code warned that parquet-tools are not included in the path. After installing parquet-tools, I no longer see this warning however I suspect the path is the issue.

Anyhow, my knowledge about environment variables and adding paths is rather limited, all I can do is edit my .bash_profile. I am not sure what Visual Code needs me to do when it requests that I add parquet-tools to its path, I am guessing that it has a CLI tool that somehow needs to search for the installed binaries in its own path? Is there a way I can edit that? Or does it just want me to add parquet-tools to my .bash_profile?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @h0r53 I'm afraid not, I decided it's less effort to have a notebook open with a spark environment to just read the parquet file if I really need to see the contents.